# JSON property have dynamic name

Tags: javascript, json

I'm tryng to access at value of property `id`,

 but the name `(156_teamtoteam_male_863458)` is dynamic. 
How I can do that?

```
data: {
  '156_teamtoteam_male_863458': {
    t: {
      id: '863458',
      nm: 'ATP Cup, Group C',
```

The name is not ever "156_teamtoteam_male_863458" but can change and I dont know how it is called the next time.
I would something like `console.log(JSON.data.*.t.id);`

Comment: `JSON.data[dynamic_variable].t.id`

Comment: The name is not ever "156_teamtoteam_male_863458" but can change and I dont know how it is called the next time.@Barmar

Comment: I assumed it was in a variable. You can use `Object.values(JSON.data)[0].t.id`.